# create react app on windows does not work

Tags: create-react-app

On windows, create-react-app command does not work after installing node (latest stable version).

also after trying to uninstall node and clear the npm cache.

below, a screen of the console when the process is blocked

[screen console when create react app stops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp0sW.png)

I have no error message, nor any unlocking leads

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please share more details - what **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: I run the create-react-app command and the console display stops (see screen). I must exit the process with ctrl + x.  
this results in the creation of a folder named after the application, but which is empty. I deleted and reinstalled node, without success

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should also include the console output you are facing - I would assume this is pure text, which could be shared best as text

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have node installed,

run npm audit fix --force